Dispose is never called for any server-side blazor components
We have a .Net Core 6 app, which we are slowly transitioning UI functionality from JS to Blazor, using Blazor Server components.  For the most part everything works fine, however we introduced a couple components that have timers for refreshing status of items that can change outside of the user actions, things like network status.  Everything works fine, except that when moving away from the page that the component is on, the component's Dispose method is never called, which leaves the timer running.
Here is how the component is called from the cshtml page:
<component type="typeof(APStatus)" render-mode="Server" /\>

Here is the timer definition in the OnInitializedAsync.
_timer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);
_timer.Elapsed += CountDownTimer;
_timer.Start();
_timer.Enabled = true;

Here is the CountDownTimer callback:
public async void CountDownTimer(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_internalCounter > 0)
    {
        _internalCounter -= 1;
    }
    else
    {
        _timer.Enabled = false;
        _timer.Stop();
    }
    await InvokeAsync(async () =>
    {
        if (NetInfo != null)
        {
            await GetApStatus();
            
        }
    });
}

Here is Dispose Method:
public void Dispose()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Disposing Happened");
    _timer.Enabled = false;
    _timer.Stop();
    _timer.Dispose();
    _timer = null;   
}

I added a CircuitHandler, same problem, I get OnCircuitOpenAsync events, but the Closed Circuit never fires.
Here is some of the CircuitHandler code:
public override Task OnCircuitClosedAsync(Circuit circuit, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    Console.WriteLine("OnCircuitClosedAsync");
    Circuits.TryRemove(circuit.Id, out var circuitRemoved);
    OnCircuitsChanged();
    return base.OnCircuitClosedAsync(circuit, cancellationToken);
}

I have tried virtually everything I can think of, gone through the Program.cs, various ways of calling the component, everything seems to be working fine from the chrome dev tools standpoint, no strange error messages in the logs.
I turned on blazor logging, and that hasn't shown anything.
I have searched virtually every forum I can find for someone with a similar problem, but can't find anything on why this would be occurring.
I have other blazor components on site, everything is working fine.  I've added Dispose to all of those, and none of them ever get fired.
I've updated to the latest .net core 6 packages, no luck.
I started a fresh project, and implemented the Microsoft code for a timer in a blazor component, it works fine, the Dispose is called as expected when navigating away from the page.
When I copied that component into our project, everything works fine, but when I navigate away from the page with the component on, nothing, Dispose is never called.
Here is the counter Example:
@page "/counter"
@using System.Timers
@using System.Diagnostics
@implements IDisposable
<PageTitle\>Counter\</PageTitle\>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>

<p>Current count: @timerCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount"\>Click me\</button\>

@code {
private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
    private int timerCount = 0;
    private Timer timer = new(1000);
    
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        timer.Elapsed += (sender, eventArgs) => OnTimerCallback();
        timer.Start();
    }
    
    private void OnTimerCallback()
    {
        _ = InvokeAsync(() =>
        {
            timerCount++;
            StateHasChanged();
        });
    }
    
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Disposing");
        timer.Dispose();
    }

}

Update 1
After lots of researching and tweaking of things mainly related to circuits, I set DisconnectedCircuitRetentionPeriod using this in the Program.cs
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor().AddCircuitOptions(options =>
{
    options.DetailedErrors = true;
    options.DisconnectedCircuitRetentionPeriod = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
});

This took the time to dispose from about 3.5 mins to 10 seconds or less.  Still working on trying to understand why this is necessary, but seems like progress.
Update 2
After testing this and all the other blazor components on the site, this appears to have solved the issue and hasn't seem to cause any other issues.  After doing more research I found this question and answer as well, and seems to indicate that it can solve this type of problem of disposing of components.
I'm not sure why this isn't more common when trying to dispose in certain situations.  I hope this helps someone else.

I believe Dispose is called by the Renderer when it removes the component from the RenderTree.  So your behaviour would suggest that the Renderer is holding the reference to the component for some reason.  So that begs the question: What are you doing with your component tree that is different?  There has to be something.

Thank you for the direction.  I was researching the same thing last night, it does't seem like it can have anything to do with how we've implemented the individual blazor components or are referencing them within pages, as the Counter example would have worked just fine.  The only blazor related items outside of that are in the Program.cs and the ref to _framework/blazor.server.js in the _Layout.cshtml.  Seems like the only culprit really could be that there is something in Program.cs that is systematically stepping on the typical RenderTree update process.

Can you implement IDisposable on a scoped service and see it get disposed when the SPA session ends?

Update, it appears for at least the counter component, OnCircuitClosed and the Dispose is being called about 2-3 minutes after browsing away from the page.  So something is actually delaying the circuit closing and Dispose, not eliminating it.  Will test on the other components.

In a normal Blazor app IDisposable works fine (be ware of prerendering though). So focus on that this is a Razor Pages app and  the <component ... />. How did you do that for the Counter example?

I put in a Test Disposable scoped service, it doesn't get disposed of when theoretically it should, after the response has finished sending.  The Counter component and the scoped Test component get disposed about 3 minutes after I leave the page.
Test Scoped Created5/10/2024 8:51:11 AM
Test Scoped Disposed5/10/2024 8:54:18 AM
So it seems the server either isn't actually completing the response, or the server isn't detecting correctly when the response is completed.

Henk this is the code for rendering the component, its identical to the code in both our app, and the test Blazor app that functions correctly.
<component type="typeof(APStatus)" render-mode="Server" />

Interesting solution in the end.  I've bookmarked this just in case!

The solution was adding this to the Program.cs
.AddCircuitOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.DetailedErrors = true;
                    options.DisconnectedCircuitRetentionPeriod = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
                    options.DisconnectedCircuitMaxRetained = 0;
                });

It looks like the default of the retention period is 3 minutes, which coincides with how long it takes to eventually the Dispose being called.
As mentioned in the last update, I found this question and answer, which seems to indicate that it can solve this type of problem of disposing of components.
